# Bundling different versions of a development gem depending on the ruby version

Tags: ruby, bundler, versioning

I have an application that depends on `flexmock`. For a number of reasons, I want this app to run on 1.8.7 to 2.0.0 and beyond, so far it worked really well. Since the app has a huge test suite it's been easy to maintain compatibility.

The only issue is `flexmock`. There is a bug in the older version of flexmock that I have to work around with a monkeypatch. The newer version of flexmock fixes the bug, but it only works on 1.9.3. The older version of flexmock that I use also gives test failures on 2.0.0 since it incorrectly records the number of method calls on classes like Time.

Is there a magic Bundler incantation that I can use to modify my development dependencies so that they come out with relevant versions for each version of Ruby I run on? Specifically so that it runs clean on Travis-Ci?

I do not version-control `Gemfile.lock`

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `flexmock` versions in groups, and then when you `bundle install` you can exclude the groups you don't want, so:

```
group :ruby18 do 
   gem 'flexmock', ~> oldversion
end

groups :ruby19 do
   gem 'flexmock', ~> newversion
end
```

and then when you run the app in 1.8 you can `bundle install --without ruby19` and vice versa for ruby 1.9+. See more at http://gembundler.com/v1.3/groups.html

Comment: Seems like the way to go, only I don't see any options on Travis for adding/removing Bundler groups per build environment. Maybe I missed something? http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/ruby/

Comment: http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/ruby/#Custom-Bundler-arguments-and-Gemfile-locations

Comment: Yeah but it does not specify how to tie custom Gemfiles to custom rvm rubies in `.travis.yml`